# CR2 Preview generation with Node.JS/Electron

Tags: node.js, image, electron, thumbnails, preview

I want to build a Node.JS/Electron ApplicationCache, that can show Previews for the following filetypes: DNG, CR2, JGP, TIFF. 
I have accomplished all of that using an external library. Except for CR2.

I cant find anything (free) that can generate a preview image for CR2-Files and does not require installing exiftools or imagemagick on the machine. Does anybody have an idea waht it can use?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is: dcraw